# How do I fix my navbar to center it and make it even on both sides?

Tags: html, css

The problem arises once I shrink the window down under 500px; I created a media query to change size depending on the size of the display. Unfortunately upon doing this, all the menu items seem to float to the left and there is too much empty space making things unbalanced. I've tried various centering methods but can't identify the issue. As always, help is greatly appreciated. Here are my html css work files:

```css
* {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    
}


.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;    
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; background:url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1054198/pexels-photo-1054198.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
}

.imagebox {
    margin:0px auto;
   width:800px;
}

.banner {
    font-size: 18px;
    background:rgba(0, 33,33, .3);
    color:aliceblue;
    
}

h2{
    padding:10px;
    background: #646ecb;
    min-width: 500px;
    color:#f0f1f5;
    font-size: 30pt;
    text-align: center;
}

.Logo {
         text-align: center;
         height: 130px;
         width: 260px;
     }

hr.style-one {
    border: none;
    height: 1px;
    min-width: 500px;
    margin:20px auto;
    background: #333;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #646ecb, #fff, #646ecb);
}

.navbar {
    background: teal;
    height: 40px;
    width:700px;
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 4px solid aliceblue;
}


nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    color:aliceblue;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:18px;
}

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: aliceblue;
    
    
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #a2f3fe;
;
}


nav ul li:hover ul li {
    display:block;
    background: teal;
}


nav ul li {
    float:left;
    width:140px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

nav ul ul li{
    position: relative;
    display:none;
}

h3{
    text-align: center;
    font-family:"Pathway Gothic One";
    color:aliceblue;
    margin:10 auto;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    padding: 5px;
    min-width: 700px;
    font-size: 20pt;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}



article{
    margin:20px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

 fieldset
{
    height: 20%;
    width: 70%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
    color:;
}

 @media (max-width: 500px) {
      body {
        background:url("https://c.pxhere.com/photos/07/83/adult_background_beach_black_sand_brunette_clear_sky_coast_coastline-1527307.jpg!d");
        background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height:100%;
      }
     

     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
     
     
     h2{
    padding: 20px;
    background: #646ecb;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    
}
     
     .Logo {
         text-align: center;
         height: 60px;
         width: 120px;
     }

     
 
 fieldset
{
    height: 25%;
    width: 70%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
    color:red;
}
     
     .imagebox {
         width: 700px;
         margin:0 auto;
         text-align: center;
}

     
     h3 {
         font-size:14px;
         font-family:"pathway gothic one";
         line-height:10px;
}
     
     
     hr.style-one {
    border: none;
    height: 1px;
    min-width: 400px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #646ecb, #fff, #646ecb);
         margin:4px auto;
}
     
     .navbar {
    background: teal;
    height: 30px;
    width:400px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 4px solid darkorchid;
     }


nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    color:aliceblue;
    font-size:12px;
}

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: aliceblue;
    margin:0px;
    
    
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #a2f3fe;
;
}


nav ul li:hover ul li {
    display:block;
    background: teal;
    
}


nav ul li {
    float:center;
    width:70px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

nav ul ul li{
    position: relative;
    display:none;
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

    
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/maintravel.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pathway+Gothic+One" rel="stylesheet">



  <title>Round-a-Whirl</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div></div>
      <h2><img src="HatchfulExport-All/linkedin_banner_image_1.png" height=75 width="auto" class="Logo"></h2>
    </header>
    <div class="navbar">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plane"> </i> Flights</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-hotel"> </i> Hotel</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car"> </i>  Rental</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"> </i> Discover</a>
            <ul>
              <li> Vacation</li>
              <li> Cruise</li>
              <li> City</li>
              <li> Nature</li>
              <li> Getaways</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> Deals</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
      <hr class="style-one" width="20%">
      <h3>Don't travel in Whirl! Find flights and compare</h3>
      <hr class="style-one" width="20%">
      
      
          
<head>

<style>
div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<article>
    This is a simple site I created using HTML and CSS of a travel site for the fictional Round-a-Whirl travel company. 
    <br /><br />
    <p class="banner">Check out our all inclusive vacation packages!</p>
  </article>
    
    <fieldset>
    <form>
        
Origin:<input type="text" name="Origin">  
        Destination:<input type="text"><br /><br />
      
Depart:<input type="date">
Return:<input type="date">
        
        </form></fieldset>
    

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: You have a fair few elements which are using hard-coded widths set to hundreds of pixels. I'd recommend changing all of these to use percentage-based values; then your layout should correct itself, and you likely won't even have to worry about media queries at all :)

Comment: This was a perfect suggestion so I'll also consider it the perfect answer, thank you!

Comment: You don't need to use medaQ. Just give values in percentage and you'll be good to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
     @media (max-width: 500px)
nav ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 103px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
hope this will help you
```